# Div drops to next line when excess text is present

Tags: html, css

Whenever there is excess text inside the `.story` class, the `<div>` drops to the next line. Setting a fixed width is not possible as it needs to be responsive and the text would not wrap around the `<div>` anyway.

Hiding the overflow just hides the `<div>`, and `white-space: nowrap` has no effect. Am I missing something simple here? Thanks a lot!

```css
.break{
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
      background: #fff;
}
.breakBox{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #000000;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1088px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.breakBox>div.title {
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    background: #FFEF00;
    color: #000000;
}
.breakBox>div {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 12px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.breakBox>div.story {
    left: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="break">
       
    <div class="breakBox">
        <div class="title">some text here</div>
     <div class="story">
            
            More text goes here... More text goes here... More text goes here... More text
            
        </div>
    </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: If you truly want to have it responsive, then you'll need to get rid of all those explicit heights and widths.  You said that setting a fixed width is not possible but you have set fixed widths/heights on every element.  Could you explain a bit more what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i just want to have the yellow and black divs side-by-side and adjust heights to fit the content

Comment: does [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvbxra) work for you?  It's fully responsive, and `divs` are side-by-side with auto-adjusting heights to fit the content.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reduce font size of `.story` div. 
If you add more content to `.story` you need to again reduce `font-size` accordingly.

```css
.break{
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
      background: #fff;
}
.breakBox{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #000000;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1088px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.breakBox>div.title {
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    background: #FFEF00;
    color: #000000;
}
.breakBox>div {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 12px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.breakBox>div.story {
    left: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="break">
       
    <div class="breakBox">
        <div class="title">some text here</div>
     <div class="story">
            
            More text goes here... More text goes here... More text goes here... More text
            
        </div>
    </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: is there no way of wrapping it rather than reducing the font size? this isn't feasible as it will vary each time more text is created

Comment: But you can't keep in single line if you add more content. You need increase the parent div width or content size smaller than your parent div

Comment: why dont u use `span` tag instead of `<div>` for showing ur story

Comment: Even if you add span it will go on second line.

Comment: Setting the .title to 40% and .story to 60% wide is adequate, but how do you get the text to wrap?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please use `height:auto` in `.breakBox>div`. you used `height:40px` and this is the problem. Thanks

Comment: sorry but this does nothing

Comment: In breakBox you used 1088px width. And for responsiveness you need to use 100%.

Answer (score 0):

How about remove  `display: block;` and `float: left;`
from  `.breakBox>div.story` ?